# Expo - Android build error - package R does not exist

Tags: react-native, expo, build-error

Expo build error Image

[image: 1]

I'm trying to build android apk, but expo show this error like image above, i dont' know how to fix this, i don't have Android folder so i cannot change anything inside
Thank you

How to resolved this error without Android folder?

Answer (score 5):

If you are building without expo eject or expo prebuild Then you must try this solution. [21784](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21784#issuecomment-1493563686)
Otherwise, if you are building Expo eject(with an Android folder) Then you can
make sure that the namespace in `android/app/build.gradle` was correct and that ReactNativeFlipper.java in the release folder is created with the wrong package name. Change it

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the expo-cli from the project and globally.
i.e:

`npm uninstall expo-cli`
`npm uninstall -g expo-cli`

Now I run `npm run start`. And type '**s**' for **Expo Go**, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, when I run
`npx expo run:android`

The generated build.gradle has a com.packagename that is different than the app.json com.companyname.packagename

fixing it manually after generated, helped me.